# Add and remove class when scrolling specific distance but in different @media sizes

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm stuck on a bit of coding.

I need some help with nesting multiple if and else statements.

What I am trying to make is a code snippet that adds and removes a class when scrolling. But I would like to target three @media sizes.

I have been testing the following two code snippets and they work:

**Code snippet #1**

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 && $(window).width() <= 1100) {
              console.log($(this).scrollTop() + ' ' + $(window).width());

    $('.services-breadcrumb').addClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
  }
  else{
    $('.services-breadcrumb').removeClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
  }
});
```

**Code snippet #2**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scroll > 50 ){

    $('.services-breadcrumb').addClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
  }
  else{
    $('.services-breadcrumb').removeClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
  }
});
```

---

I would like to create nested if and else statements for three different @media sizes (1100> | <1100 | <767).

This is what I have been playing around with the following code snippet but I have had no success.

**Test code snippet #1**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1100) {      
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').addClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
                  }
         else {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').removeClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
         }

    } else if($(window).width() <= 1100) {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 75) {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').addClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
                  }
         else {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').removeClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
         }
     } else if($(window).width() <= 767) {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').addClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
                  }
         else {
               $('.services-breadcrumb').removeClass('services-breadcrumb-scroll-nav');
         }
     }
 });
```

I really need some help, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if the width is smaller than 767, it automatically is also smaller than 1100. that means it will  never reach the third condition. You need something like `$(window).width() <= 1100 && $(window).width() > 767)`

Comment: `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 && $(window).width() <= 1100)` replace `width()` with `innerWidth()` function.

Comment: Your nested condition might be in this order `if ($(window).width() >= 1100)` then `else if($(window).width() <= 767)` then `else if($(window).width() < 1100)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. I really appreciate them.

Comment: Asfan, thank you so much. Your edit has fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help. You are awesome!